# g++ Incomplete type for ifstream, correct header files present

Tags: c++, file-io

Good Morning,

I am attempting to read a file using C++ compiled with g++ (g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3).  Tis compiles and works under MSVC 2008

Much trimmed here is my code:

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <fstream>

   int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
   {
      const char filename[] ("~/Serial.Number")

      std::ifstream           afile       ( fileName );
       if ( afile.is_open() )
       {
          // read input
          afile.close();
       }
    }
```

Everything I've read says this is sufficient to make an input file work.  When I write it (repeated attempts) the Eclipse cursor-over "compiler" says that 'afile" is an ifstream.  Yet after i compile it hovering over "afile' again I get "Incomplete type...".

Stranger still, when I run the program (debug mode) It runs, no errors, no exceptions thrown, but the file is never opened and the .is_open() is false.

Any ideas?

Wes

Comment: I suspect that you cannot use the "~" in the name. AFAIK, the "~" character is only expanded by shell on command line.

Comment: Oops, I typed it wrong. It really was a forward slash.
And, yes, the ~ was my real problem. Never knew that a non-existant file would reveal itself as an incomplete type. Very interesting.

Thanks,  Wes

Answer (score 3):

There is very probably no file named `~\Serial.Number` on your Linux system. It does not mean what you probably want (a file named `Serial.Number` under your home directory).

The file path `~\Serial.Number` on Linux, when passed to `open` system call or to C++ file stream, would mean a file name starting with a tilde `~` followed by a backslash `\` which is very unlikely (even if possible in principle) to exist.

You probably want to retrieve the home directory using `getenv("HOME")` and catenate that to the `"/Serial.Number"` string (starting with an ordinary slash not a backslash).

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The `~` and the `\S` looks suspect to me.  As @wilx has pointed out this is meaningful only to the shell and not file I/O methods.  Build the fullpath with the user's `$HOME` environment variable:

```
std::string fullpath = getenv("HOME");
fullpath += "/Serial.Number";
...
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems:

- If g++ is successfully compiling the code, then it is (obviously) able to resolve the necessary types, even if Eclipse's C++ parser for whatever reason can't.  Getting Eclipse to properly resolve types is a separate question.
- Using `~` in your filename probably won't do what you expect.  Using it from a Unix or Linux shell refers to your home directory because the shell expands it to your home directory, but using it from application code refers to a literal `~` directory.
- The backslash is the C and C++ escape character.  So `\S` is a special character (just like `\n` is a newline). Since `\S` in particular isn't one of the C and C++ escape characters, I'm surprised your compiler isn't complaining.  You should instead escape your backslash (i.e., `"~\\Serial.number"`) for Windows, or use forward slashes (`"~/Serial.number"`) for Linux (which will also work in Windows), or use a cross-platform library (like [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm)) which will take care of path differences for you.